# dataframe plot - remove the column names

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

```
average_curves_norm_T2
```

[image]

```
   fig, ax= plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(18,10))
    average_curves_norm_T2.xs(0, level=1).T.plot(ax=ax, legend=True, alpha=0.05, color='blue', label= f'Cluster {cluster}')
    average_curves_norm_T2.xs(0, level=1).median().plot(ax=ax, color='blue', alpha=0.9)
    
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1,96))
    ax.set_ylabel('Normalized kilowatts')
    ax.set_xlabel('Quarter Hour')
    ax.set_title('Blue - Cluster 0 | Red - Cluster 1 | Green - Cluster 2',
                 fontweight ="bold")
    ax.legend()
```

[image]

See picture for my dataframe & the chart I'm trying to plot.
The chart below contains all the MT_*** for the cluster 1.
But the small box( **MT_012,MT_013,MT_014, etc**) on the right hand side of the chart is too long to fit into the graph. Any idea how to remove that from the plot to make the plot looks cleaner?

Comment: This is the figure legend, so remove your call to ax.legend() or set the legend to False and it will be removed.

Comment: It worked! Thanks.. didn't know it was that simple..